# MFC C++ static library linked with non MFC console app

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc, static-libraries

I'm trying to compile a console program that uses a static library implementing CString.The console app has been created with the VS wizard with :
Win32 console application with precompiled headers, SDL verification but without ATL or MFC.
The static library is a MFC static library (wizard construction).

Where is (are) my mistake(s) ?

This is what I so long have tried:

I've created a new console app using MFC controls - this compile fine with the static library.

Then I've controlled and modified when necessary every link options, comparing the 2 console projects.
But the 1st console application does not compile.
I'm stucked ! 
I'm working with Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 10.

Here is the code :
File TestLib.h

```
#pragma once
#include <atlstr.h>

class TestLib
{
public:
    TestLib(){};
    TestLib(const CString &tst);
    virtual ~TestLib(void);
private:
    CString _tst;
};
```

Fichier TestLib.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestLib.h"

TestLib::TestLib(const CString &tst)
    : _tst(tst)
{
}

TestLib::~TestLib(void)
{
}
```

Fichier ConsoleTest2.cpp

```
// ConsoleTest2.cpp : définit le point d'entrée pour l'application console.
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "TestLib.h"

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    TestLib *tst = new TestLib(); // This compile fine !
    //TestLib *tst = new TestLib(_T("Test")); // This generates LNK2019 link error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What files did you include in the stdafx.h? Using the ATL headers isn't sufficient when using the MFC. You have to include afx.h! Otherwise feel free to use the ATL only (CString is a template that is part of the ATL too.

Comment: The stdafx.h file includes targetver.h, stdio.h and tchar.h... I just used the project wizard generator to get standard files and then add the Lib class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, thanks to Jochen Arndt

Just have to change the TestLib declaration to

```
TestLib::TestLib(LPCTSTR str)
    : _tst(str)
{
}
```